# Inserting records into different tables of the same MySQL Schema

Tags: java, mysql, sql

So I can successfully insert information into one table called "parts" using the code:

```
String sql1 = "INSERT INTO parts(PART1, PART2, PART3, PART4, PART5)" + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement prepareStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);

    prepareStatement.setString(1,strarr.StringArray[0][0]);
    prepareStatement.setString(2,strarr.StringArray[0][1]);
    prepareStatement.setString(3,strarr.StringArray[0][2]);
    prepareStatement.setString(4,strarr.StringArray[0][3]);
    prepareStatement.setString(5,strarr.StringArray[0][4]);

    prepareStatement.execute();
```

However when I then try to insert some data into a different table, called `subsubparts` of the same schema in the exact same why it throws up an error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2.1, 2.2, 2.3,
>   2.4, 2.5)VALUES('$$$Epidemiology of the Disease\r\nLiterature sea' at line 1

and this is on the line which executes the preparedStatement.

Below is the code of the second way which fails (if this helps):

```
String sql2 = "INSERT INTO subsubparts(2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5)" + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement0 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);

    preparedStatement0.setString(1, strarr.StringArray[2][0]);
    preparedStatement0.setString(2, strarr.StringArray[2][1]);
    preparedStatement0.setString(3, strarr.StringArray[2][2]);
    preparedStatement0.setString(4, strarr.StringArray[2][3]);
    preparedStatement0.setString(5, strarr.StringArray[2][4]);

    preparedStatement0.execute();
```

Whats even more confusing is that if throws a `com.mysql.jdbc` exception when I have imported `import java.sql.SQLException`.

Any help would be great please!!

Answer (score 0):

You second query looks wrong:

```
INSERT INTO subsubparts(2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
```

Should be changed to:

```
INSERT 
INTO subsubparts(FieldName1,FieldName2, FieldName3, FieldName4, FieldName5) 
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
```

Or if 2.1 is the name of the column then the name must be quoted e.g. "2.1"

Comment: Or if 2.1 is the name of the column then the name must be quoted e.g. `2.1`

Comment: That's what I have called my field names in the table... should I change those them to letters instead of numbers? I'll give it a go anyway...

Comment: @AleksiYrttiaho Quoted meaning placed in quotation marks

Comment: Updated the answer, you need to add quotes if these are the names. though you should consider renaming them.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been very active lately and missed that a backtick denote a code block in a comment.

Comment: Changing the 2.1 to words worked!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If your Columns names are numbers like `2.1` then wrap it with quotes like,

```
String sql2 = "INSERT INTO subsubparts(`2.1`, `2.2`, `2.3`, `2.4`, `2.5`)" 
              + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

The major difference I see between the two queries is query two has periods in the column name.  MySQL won't recognize this as-is.  Instead, you need to quote each of the column names with backticks:

```
(`2.1`, `2.2`, `2.3`, `2.4`, `2.5`)
```

It may also be possible to use double-quotes.  See the [MySQL documentation on identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html) for more detail.